# Numerical verification of solution.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have the non-linear equation
\begin{align}
& \left( -\frac{1}{4}\left({\frac { \left( 4\,{x}^{3}+2\,
ex \right) ^{2}}{ \left( {x}^{4}+e{x}^{2}+f \right) ^{3/2}}}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left({
\frac {12\,{x}^{2}+2\,e}{\sqrt {{x}^{4}+e{x}^{2}+f}}} \right)\right) \\ &+\frac{1}{2} \left({
\frac {x \left( 4\,{x}^{3}+2\,ex \right)  \left( 8\,a{x}^{2}-8\,a+1
 \right) }{\sqrt {{x}^{4}+e{x}^{2}+f}}} \right) \\ &-\quad 4\left( 4\,a{x}^{2}+{a}^{2}
+C-2\,a \right) \sqrt {{x}^{4}+e{x}^{2}+f}=0 
\end{align}
where $x \in  [-7,15]$ and $a \in \mathbb{Q}$. I want to solve this one numerically such that this equation is fulfilled for arbitrary $x \in [-7,15]$ and one parameter $a$ that is entered a priori. So, essentially I want to determine $f,e,C$ such that this equation is fulfilled for the chosen $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and all $ x \in [-7,15]$. Hence, $f,e,C \in \mathbb{Q}$ must be constant and therefore independent of $x$.

Comment: Still confused what you're trying to do. It seems like you're trying to figure out the domain of the parameter space for $f,e,$ and $C$ given any value of $a$?

Comment: Have you explored the implicit function theorem, treating $x$ as a constant fixed in $[-1,1]$, and considering your equation as a function of four variables, $a, e, f, C$? You can use it to identify regions in which $e, f, C$ are solvable in terms of $a$.

Comment: What are you doing with $x$? It almost sounds like a root finding problem, but apparently you want $e, f, C$ to be functions of $x$. It's still not clear. Is $x$ fixed, or do you want $e, f, C$ to be functions of $x \in [-1,1]$?

Comment: If you're fixing $a$, and can fix $x$, just use Broyden's method to find the roots in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: They're only independent in your solutions above because they make the coefficients of the x terms zero. There are more solutions than that. It's like what solves $(a^2-1)(x^2+ax+1)=0$. One set of solutions is $\pm 1$, the other set is *dependent* on $ x$, no way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First. I want to mention a naive brute-force numerical scheme. If you are looking to solve a set of equations $f_x(a,e,f,c)=0$ for a continuous range of $x$, you can always try picking three values of $x$ at random from $[-1,1]$, and, given $a$, try to solve the three equations $f_x(a,e,f,c)=0$ in three unknowns $e,f,c$ numerically. The numerical solver might not always succeed, but you can try many different starting points for $e,f,c$ at random, and pick different values of $x$. I actually tried this scheme, and it kind of works, finding two or three of the analytical solutions that you gave. I used the default FindRoot solver in Mathematica with no special options at all.

Second. If you multiply your equation by $(x^4+ex^2+f)^{3/2}$ (which is nonzero for almost all $x$, so this is fine), you get the following polynomial in $x$ that has to vanish identically:
$$ -e f+8 a f^2-4 a^2 f^2-4 c f^2+\left(-6 f+2 e f+8 a e f-8 a^2 e f-8 c e f-16 a f^2\right) x^2\\+\left(-3 e+e^2-4 a^2 e^2-4 c e^2+8 f-8 a^2 f-8 c f-24 a e f\right) x^4\\+\left(-2+6 e-8 a e-8 a^2 e-8 c e-8 a e^2-16 a f\right) x^6+\left(4-8 a-4 a^2-4 c-8 a e\right) x^8. $$
All the coefficients of $x$ therefore also have to vanish, and all these coefficients are polynomials $q_k$ in $a, e, f, c$.

Someone better familiar with algebraic geometry can explain this better than I can, but I'll try. The set of all $a, e, f, c$ that make all $q_k$ vanish simultaneously is called the ideal generated by the $q_k$'s. [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/tutorial/tour_polynomial.html) can help here. This ideal will have a [Groebner basis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroebnerBasis.html), which is a set of "simpler" polynomials that have precisely the same roots. It will also have a ["primary decomposition"](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/polynomial_rings/sage/rings/polynomial/multi_polynomial_ideal.html) into "primary ideals", which gives a set of sets of polynomials such that each solution to the original system of polynomial equations solves *one* of the sets of polynomial equations in the primary decomposition.

The primary ideals are also guaranteed to have some mathematical properties that I find mysterious. It's like if you want to solve $(x-1)(y-1)(z-1)=0$, then the three primary ideals will be $\{x-1\}$, $\{y-1\}$ and $\{z-1\}$.

The point of this is that when I tried to solve your problem in sage, it gave me the following primary decomposition of the ideal:

```
x,a,e,f,c = QQ['x,a,e,f,c'].gens()
P = (-1 + x**2)*(e*f + 6*f*x**2 + 3*e*x**4 + 2*x**6) + \
  x**2*(e + 2*x**2)*(f + e*x**2 + x**4)*(1 + 8*a*(-1 + x**2)) - \
  4*(f + e*x**2 + x**4)**2*(a**2 + c + a*(-2 + 4*x**2))
PC = [P.coefficient({x:k}) for k in range(0, 1+P.degree(x), 2)]
I = ideal(PC)
I.primary_decomposition()

[Ideal (f, e + 1, a^2 + c - 1)
   of Multivariate Polynomial Ring in x, a, e, f, c over Rational Field,
 Ideal (8*a*f - 16*e*c - 32*f*c - 4*a - e - 9, e^2 - 4*f,
        a*e + 4*e*c + 8*f*c + a + 2, a^2 - 8*e*c - 16*f*c + c - 5,
        64*f^2*c - 32*e*c - 128*f*c - 8*a - 10*e + 20*f - 19,
        16*e*f*c + 8*e*c + 48*f*c + 2*a + 5*e + 5)
   of Multivariate Polynomial Ring in x, a, e, f, c over Rational Field]
```

Now all that's left is the two solve each set of polynomial equations in $e,f,c$ in terms of $a$, so there is no need for a numerical approach any more.

The two primary ideals it returned correspond exactly to the three analytical solutions you mentioned in your post ($f=0,e=-1,c=1-a^2$ and the two solutions to quadratic equations). If sage's calculation is correct, this is also a proof that there are no other solutions to your problem, so there is no point in looking for them. Indeed, I found none when I used the brute-force numerical scheme.

Comment: @user108886 Yes, it is a systematic way of doing that, and can be done automatically by sage instead of by hand. It also doesn't "lose" any solutions.